# http into a service with Angular2 with es5

Tags: http, angular, ecmascript-5

I am working with Angular2 and es5. I want to use http in a service.
Unfortunately I have 2 errors:
 - http is undefined, but ng.http.Http is defined,
 - I have this error for the main component:

```
vendor-client.min.js:28 EXCEPTION: Can't resolve all parameters for class0: (t, ?)
```

Here is my service code:

```
;(function(app, ng) {
  console.log(new ng.http.Http());

  app.ApplicationsService = ng.core.Injectable().Class({
    constructor: [ng.http.Http, function(http) {
      console.log(http);
      this.applicationsEmailUrl = 'api/applications/email';
      this.http = http;
    }],

    emailExists: function(email) {
      console.log(email);
      var data = { email: email };
      return this.http.post(this.applicationsEmailUrl, data)
        .toPromise()
        .then(function(response) { response.json().data; })
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

  });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}), window.ng);
```

Here is the main component:

```
;(function(app, ng) {

  app.AppComponent = ng.core
    .Component({
      selector: 'register-form',
      templateUrl: 'src/register/app.component.html'
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: [ng.core.ElementRef, app.ApplicationsService, function(ref, Applications) {
        console.log('app.component.js');
        this.programs = JSON.parse(ref.nativeElement.getAttribute('programs'));
        this.applications = Applications;
      }],
      emailExists: function(email) {
        console.log('emailExists() triggered');
        Applications.emailExists(email);
      }
    });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}), window.ng);
```

The bootstrap:

```
;(function(app, ng) {

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ng.platformBrowserDynamic.bootstrap(app.AppComponent, [
      ng.forms.disableDeprecatedForms(),
      ng.forms.provideForms(),
      ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS,
      app.ApplicationsService
    ]);
  });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}), window.ng);
```

If I try to inject http into the main component within the providers array, it works. But I would rather prefer to have a service.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. Looks like Angular2 needs to load your code in order. The main component was loaded before the service, so it was undefined. I put all my code in one file and it works. I will use a require loader asap.